# ZF2 - Add a Form within a view that has a Controller already

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, view, controller

I'm developing a website using ZF2, and I am trying to add a Form for comments called `CommentForm.php` within my view `rxe/view/id.phtml`. I want to render it as a comment `textarea`, but I've tried many ways and in the end I always get the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/vol12_3/byethost4.com/b4_16354889/htdocs/module/Rxe/view/rxe/view/id.phtml`.

I have a Login `Form` but it has its own view, unlike the Comment.

I posted my code in my [github](https://github.com/mfgabriel92/rxe/tree/master/module/Rxe/src/Rxe) for you to see it better than seeing all the code pasted in here.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: how you pass commentForm to commentController?

Comment: Check https://github.com/mfgabriel92/rxe/blob/master/module/Rxe/src/Rxe/Factory/CommentControllerFactory.php#L16